# why is this button doesn't change appearance even though I already change the background color

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbAkc.png)

please help me change the button color in android studio

Comment: Please share the relevant code as well

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71614383/edit) your question with a [mcve] . Do not add images of code add code in code format.

Comment: If it is material button then use `app:backgroundTint`

Answer (score 0):

Use AppcompatButton and give any backgroud you want to give

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_delay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:background=""
        android:ems="10"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use android:backgroundTint

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"/>
```